# Importrange Excel formula with Google Drive

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to link the total on one Spreadsheet on Google Drive to another, using the formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yniigLO-KgKCmFgxm1ie7SXkAsixJjtSXiDk7jTOSCU/edit#gid=1526816789", "8FebTRANSLATIONFROMOXONIAN:DOROTHYSAYERSINRUSSIA!C:21")
```

I have changed the sheet's name, but the cell still shows 'error'. Could it be that I need to set a special permission in the document?

P.S: I have tried linking the whole column to with no result, using ";" instead of a comma, and putting the name of the sheet into single inverted commas.

Comment: Lina - are the Spreadsheets Excel or Google-Sheets?  If Excel, have you walked through the formula to see which part is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1yniigLO-KgKCmFgxm1ie7SXkAsixJjtSXiDk7jTOSCU";
             "8FebTRANSLATIONFROMOXONIAN:DOROTHYSAYERSINRUSSIA!C:21")
```

is a valid formula if your sheet (tab) name is really: **`8FebTRANSLATIONFROMOXONIAN:DOROTHYSAYERSINRUSSIA`**

make sure both sheets are not private (if both of them are not yours), and also make sure you allow access to them otherwise you will get **`#REF!`** error